# check.torproject.org times out using TorBrowser 6.0.5

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I was just automatically updated to TOR Browser 6.0.5 on Windows. When I check for TORness at check.torproject.org, I get "Problem Loading Page. The connection has timed out. The server at check.torproject.org is taking too long to respond." Etc.

This has been consistent over the last few hours. Some other torproject.org URLs also time out but many torproject.org pages do load quickly. Computer connectivity to many other non-TOR sites is fine.

Is this a bug in the new 6.0.5 or is this a problem with the check.torproject.org page itself?

THANK YOU.

Comment: Did this persist after a New Identity was used and does it still persist now? Everything works fine for me on 6.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

[check.torproject.org](https://check.torproject.org) is working fine now. The Tor Project servers were probably having temporary issues.

For future reference, if a specific website times out, but other websites load normally, it's most likely a temporary problem with the website.

Answer (score 0):

On Sunday, September 18th, https://check.torproject.org/ as well as some other services were temporarily down. So it was not a problem with your installation. By now all should be working normally.